# Set CultureInfo in Asp.net Core to have a . as CurrencyDecimalSeparator instead of ,

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm going mad. I just want the culture used in the entire Asp.net core application to be set to "en-US". But nothing seems to work. Where to I set the culture for the entire application? I'm not interested in client browser cultures and what not. The only thing that seems to change it is changing the language settings of Windows. I just want the culture to be determined from within the application itself, not by the client.

What I have tried so far:

- Set `<system.web><globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" /></system.web>` in web.config
- Set `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;` and `CurrentUICulture` in Startup.Configure and even in the controller.
- Use `app.UseRequestLocalization(..` as shown below

  ```
      var enUsCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
      var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
      {
          SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
          {
              enUsCulture
          },
          SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
          {
              enUsCulture
          },
          DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(enUsCulture),
          FallBackToParentCultures = false,
          FallBackToParentUICultures = false,
          RequestCultureProviders = null
      };

      app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
  ```

But nothing seems to change the CurrencyDecimalSeparator from (nl-NL) , to (en-US).

How can the culture be set?

**EDIT:**
@soren
This is how the configure method looks like. I've put a breakpoint on `DetermineProviderCultureResult` but it is never hit while visiting the website.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, FinOsDbContext context)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        //TODO: Clean up
        //var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        // UseCookieAuthentication..
        // UseJwtBearerAuthentication..

        //add userculture provider for authenticated user
        var requestOpt = new RequestLocalizationOptions();
        requestOpt.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US")
        };
        requestOpt.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US")
        };
        requestOpt.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
        requestOpt.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new SingleCultureProvider());

        app.UseRequestLocalization(requestOpt);

        FinOsDbContext.Initialize(context);
        FinOsDbContext.CreateTestData(context);
    }

    public class SingleCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
    {
        public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => new ProviderCultureResult("en-US", "en-US"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: .net core don't look at web.config anymore, but everything you had done was so right Mike. I have a few multilingual project in .net core 1.0.1. could you share more code from your Startup.cs...

Comment: Shouldn't `UseRequestLocalization` be placed _before_ `UseMvc`? Othewise Mvc will have already handled the request by the time the `UseRequestLocalization`middleware runs

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This is what solves it for me:

Setting the following in `StartUp.Configure`

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Comment: I was working with CsvHelper when I encoutered this problem. This trick worked out. Thanks!

Comment: Mike has you seen the answer from user mindingdata ? It seems that is the way to go...

Comment: @Pascal I've not tried it myself. If more people are upvoting your comment, or the other answer, I am of course willing to make that the accepted answer. Judge me, but I have no motivation right now to try it out myself :$.

Comment: @Pascal UseRequestLocalization is a different thing, it does set the application to use the client locale, which is totally different from setting the culture globally for all users

Comment: This comment is a little off-topic for this thread but worth mentioning for anyone who's using `en-US` as the thread culture in Europe: Please don't set US as the culture because it puts all dates into month-day-year format, which is *not* what all other countries outside of the USA use, and it only serves to confuse. If you're using English on a European website then please consider using `en-GB` in order to display the dates in the European format. Write US English. into your en-GB resource files if you really prefer but please don't set the UI culture as `en-US` on a European website.

Comment: You can also put this in the `Main` function in `Program.cs` instead of in the `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: This worked for me for the Blazor server-side and I was able to change the culture without the use of cookies

Comment: Unbelievably in 2023 with .net 8 I have had to do this as well because in docker container using the default images it is coming back with the iv invariant culture despite turning invariant culture off in project file and set env variable inside container.

Comment: This solution works with a BackgroundService or IHostedService; the other solutions with RequestLocalization are applicable for the website itself.

Answer (score 55):

A bit late but here is what worked for me:

```
var defaultDateCulture = "fr-FR";
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

// Configure the Localization middleware
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    }
});
```

Comment: IMHO, here's a nice article explaining what's going on: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/06/22/request-culture-asp-net-core/

Comment: tested and worked good on dotnet 6 also, just add before `app.UseRouting();` line.

Answer (score 33):

Your code looks all fine. The issue is your call to

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(...);
```

Needs to happen before your call to

```
app.UseMvc();
```

The reason your breakpoint is never hit is because it never goes that far. UseMVC completes the request and returns the result. Remember, Middleware happens in order and any one of the middleware can shortcircuit the process and halt processing going any further.

Comment: it works like a charm!!!

Comment: For .NET Core 3.x and later I think this should be added before `app.UseRouting()`

Answer (score 29):

Localization is configured in the **Startup.ConfigureServices** method:

```
CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
           {
            new CultureInfo("ar"),
            new CultureInfo("fa"),
            new CultureInfo("en")
        };

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ar");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                };

        });
```

**Startup.Configure** method

```
 app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

then `UseRequestLocalization` initializes a `RequestLocalizationOptions` object. This should be placed atleast before your **UseMvc** call

**Change Culture:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new     RequestCulture(culture)),
    new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

**Current language:**

```
var currentLanguage = HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture.Name;
```

Comment: This is summery of whole answers. and should validate as a accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me

```
 Response.Cookies.Append(
         CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
         CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(lang)),
         new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET 7 short answer:

```cs
    app.UseRequestLocalization("en-US");
```

Note:

> The localization middleware must be configured before any middleware that might check the request culture (for example, app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()).

For detailed explanation:

[Implement a strategy to select the language/culture for each request in a localized ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

Only configuring in startup didn't work for me

```
 services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var ksCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("sq");
                var enCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en");
                var srCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("sr");

                ksCultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    ksCultureInfo,
                    enCultureInfo,
                    srCultureInfo
                };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: enCultureInfo, uiCulture: ksCultureInfo);
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                };
            });
```

I added jquery globalize validation plugins:
Then you need to use Globalize with jquery-validation-globalize plugin. [Saw this here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420)

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick answer based on the accepted one and the others :

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Tested and worked on : dotNet 6

PS : writed on program.cs (because there's no more Startup.cs file on Asp.net MVC 6), ensure that this lines of code are added **before** `app.UseRouting();` line