# <system.web> globalization in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, globalization, culture

I have been using the following setting the the `web.config` of my previous application.

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />
</system.web>
```

Now in my new .net core project I don't know how to put this setting in the `appsettings.json` file.

Thanks for your help,
Nikolai

Comment: possible solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72435434/12335211

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The localization is configured in the `Startup class` and can be used throughout the application. The `AddLocalization` method is used in the `ConfigureServices` to define the resources and localization. This can then be used in the Configure method. Here, the `RequestLocalizationOptions` can be defined and is added to the stack using the `UseRequestLocalization` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization()
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            services.AddScoped<LanguageActionFilter>();

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                options =>
                    {
                        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                        {
                            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                            new CultureInfo("de-CH"),
                            new CultureInfo("fr-CH"),
                            new CultureInfo("it-CH")
                        };

                        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
                        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Adding these two lines to ConfigureServices seems to have the effect you want:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
```

I tried approved answer: first of all it needs a *LanguageActionFilter*  class which is not a standard .net core class and after that it did not work for the simple purpose of using preferred culture instead of system default culture.