# How To Set Globalization Culture in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've been having some trouble with decimal numbers in asp net core mvc. I got it to work in a regular asp net app by adding this to the web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    ...
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US"/>
  </system.web>
```

But, as there isn't a web.config present in the core app, I'm not quite sure what to do. What would the closest approximation of this in core look like?

Comment: You can add a web.config to the core app.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#localization-middleware

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176558/system-web-globalization-in-net-core

Comment: possible solution at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72435434/12335211

Answer (score 7):

In Asp.Net Core ,localization is configured in the Startup.ConfigureServices method and can be used throughout the application:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddMvc()
  .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
  .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

The current culture on a request is set in the localization Middleware. The localization middleware is enabled in the `Startup.Configure` method. The localization middleware must be configured before any middleware which might check the request culture (for example, `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`).

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
 new CultureInfo("en-US"),
 new CultureInfo("fr"),
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
   DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
   // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
   SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
   // UI strings that we have localized.
   SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
 });

 app.UseStaticFiles();
 // To configure external authentication, 
 // see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

For more details , you could refer to [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request) .

Comment: Your note about setting it early in Startup.Configure just saved me a lot of pain.