# How to change the global culture number seperator from '.' to ','?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there anyway in C# to change "." to ","? I live in Belgium and here we use a comma instead of a dot. When I type for example 1,1 C# says its not a number. It only accepts 1.1 or 1.

Here's my `cshtml` code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="preSeriousness" class="control-label">Pre seriousness:</label>
    <input asp-for="preSeriousness" class="form-control" type="text" required />
    <span asp-validation-for="preSeriousness" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Here's my controller code:

```
preSeriousness = Convert.ToDouble(collection["preSeriousness"]),
```

Here's code from my start.cs configure method:

```cs
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

When I run this code it writes nl-BE:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Console.WriteLine(cultureInfo);
```

Here's an image to make it more clear:

[image]

Comment: You might find an answer here: [How to: Set a Culture for an ASP.NET Web Page](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/12062/localization/how-to-set-a-culture-for-an-aspnet-web-page)

Comment: We normally use CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture for converting string input to numeric types. If you are running your application with your local culture, why do you specify InvariantCulture while converting to double? Invariant culture uses `.` as decimal seperator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set CultureInfo in Asp.net Core to have a . as CurrencyDecimalSeparator instead of ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442444/set-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-core-to-have-a-as-currencydecimalseparator-instead)

Comment: I tried the answer of that question but without result, did post what i tried @GuruStron

Comment: What culture is set on your computer/browser?

Comment: Culture of my computer is nl-BE, same for my browser as far as i can see. Added some code to see what culture im currently using and it returns nl-BE as i have set.@GuruStron

Comment: Well, if i tried CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture but i still get the message that 1,1 is not a number.. @OguzOzgul

Comment: Can you please try to see the value of `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` ? `Convert.ToDouble(string) => double.Parse(string)` uses `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`

Comment: Can you please also `Console.WriteLine(collection["preSeriousness"])` ? Because even with the invariant culture, `1,1` is converted to `11` (does not throw) and is a number. There must be something wrong with the value!

Comment: So  this ```NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator```  returned  "," @OguzOzgul

Comment: And this ```string preSeriousness = (collection["preSeriousness"]);
                Console.WriteLine(preSeriousness);``` returned "1.1" when i did put in 1.1

Comment: The problem is that the textbox does not allow me to put in "1,1" as you can see in the image above. So i can't even submit the form with "1,1" filled in.

Comment: Then the problem is on the client side and all we look for is the server side. I am going to reproduce the problem on my Mvc test site. I live in Turkey so we also use `,` for decimal seperator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213080/discussion-between-a-vandijck-and-oguz-ozgul).