# C# .Net Core - Set global decimal delimiter regardless of culture

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I have a development machine which is a dutch machine and a english server.
Now, I have values in the database like 1.99 (string) that I need to convert to a decimal.
When I do `decimal.Parse("1.99")` I get 199.00. This is (probably) because my machine uses Dutch settings and the delimiter for a decimal is a `,` (comma).
Now, how can I set it globaly to always use a `.`(dot) as the delimiter, regardless of the culture that is beeing requested nor the machines local settings?

I'm using a .Net Core Web Api

Comment: Check this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/set-current-culture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set CultureInfo in Asp.net Core to have a . as CurrencyDecimalSeparator instead of ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442444/set-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-core-to-have-a-as-currencydecimalseparator-instead)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netcore-3.1) that uses `.` as decimal separator

```
var number = decimal.Parse("1.99", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you don't want to set the culture in every parse call, you could create an extension method

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static decimal ToDecimalInvariant(this string value)
    {
        return decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
var number = myString.ToDecimalInvariant();
```

Comment: I know, but I want to add it globally and not everywhere where I parse a decimal.

Comment: You could create an extension method `ParseInvariant(string)`

Comment: Maybe that is the best solution then. I can't get it to work by changing culture settins. Thnx

Comment: you can also set the cutlutre globally. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442444/set-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-core-to-have-a-as-currencydecimalseparator-instead

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have a wpf app, and in the main window viewmodel in the constructor I have this statement:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-Us");
```

I know this might have other (perhaps unwanted) effects on dates and other things but it works for my simple use.
I would guess that if you need it other threads you would have to do it for each thread that you start up.