# .NET Core Windows Service CultureInfo configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services

I'm currently working on a .NET Core Windows Service, implementing a couple of `BackgroundService` classes to run stuff on a timer.

All is working perfectly bar one thing - writing a date to the ILogger reference appears to be using an incorrect Culture (`en-US`) rather then the system-configured `en-AU`.

For example -

```
    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Logger.LogInformation("Started at {utcNow}", utcNow);
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

Will produce the log -

[image]

Is there a way in a Windows Service/Console app to set the Culture? I have used `UseRequestLocalization` ASP.NET Environment but it didn't seem logical in context as there would be no request.

I have tried setting all kinds of `CultureInfo...` properties with no result - any help would be appreciated.

Entry point `Program` class for reference -

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {

        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) =>
                {
                    DBLoggerConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging").Get<DBLoggerConfiguration>();
                    logging.AddDBLogger(config);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {

                    services.AddHttpClient<ISMSService, TwilioSMSService>();
                    services.AddHostedService<ExpirationSchedule>();
                    services.AddHostedService<BillingSchedule>();
                });
    }
}
```

EDIT:
It appears through some digging in the Github repo the `LogValuesFormatter` responsible for formatting parameters within the message only uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture - which leans heavily on the American way of formatting dates etc.
There appears to be no way to configure this, so I have submitted a bug in the Github repo which will hopefully get some backing - https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/3380

Comment: Did you check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442444/set-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-core-to-have-a-as-currencydecimalseparator-instead)?

Comment: No luck I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Apply this setting at this point!

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR", true) { DateTimeFormat = { ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss" } };
    
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Have a read - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40242 - in short this won't work as the Logger doesn't adhere to any culture (yet). Likely implemented in .NET 7